# Android Full Screen Video - Fragments

Tags: android, video, android-fragments, fullscreen

I have a layout which consists of a listview and a fragment. Listview lists all channels and fragment is used to play video channels. So far so good. All that works. But problem is i want the video to be full screen instead of occupying only fragment and still showing listview on left. I am not looking for code, but i want any clues on how to do it.

One way would be to get hold of cureent activity's view(listview and fragment) and swap it with a new fragment and put a surfaceview on that ? Just a guess, any insight or clue is much appreciated. I'd try what i think by tomorrow morning, till then if i'm lucky ,i'll have some clues here ;-)

Oh and last but not least, i am using surfaceview not a videoview

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, but I have a similar app using Fragments where the user can optionally "hide" the side ListView so that a photo takes up nearly the entire screen.

I ended up following this HoneycombGallery example in the Android SDK Samples which hides a "side view" via animation of the side view's width to a target width of 0 so that the photo can take up as much screen space as possible :

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/HoneycombGallery/index.html

Not sure if you will run into any issues with SurfaceView, but this might be useful.

Comment: thanks burgersmoke, i'll look into it, i appreciate your help, i guess that should be sufficient for my understanding,i was only looking for clue not code itself,so this is perfect for me, i'll give it a try and post my solution if i get it working. Once again thank you for the clue ..

Comment: So did you get this solution working?  Did you end up using this approach or something else?  I'm curious to hear how you solved it.